# Will statically linked c++ binary work on every system with same architecture?

Tags: c++, linux, static-linking

I'm making a very simple program with c++ for linux usage, and I'd like to know if it is possible to make just one big binary containing all the dependencies that would work on any linux system.

If my understanding is correct, any compiler turns source code into machine instructions, but since there are often common parts of code that can be reused with different programs, most programs depend on another libraries.

However if I have the source code for all my dependencies, I should be able to compile a binary in a way that would not require anything from the system? Will I be able to run stuff compiled on 64bit system on a 32bit system?

Comment: Do you intend to produce a 64 bit binary ? If so, 32 bit systems cannot run 64 bit code.

Comment: Did you consider making your program a [free software](http://www.fsf.org/)? This would ease a lot the issues....

Comment: Notice that libc is somehow dependent on the kernel version. So your claim is false in general (but quite true in practice)

Comment: @nos, I'm guessing I only need a 64bit binary if I need to use more than 3 gigs of ram in a single process? 32bit should do for me then.

Comment: @Bob well it depends on your CPU type. Running a 32bit app on a 64bit CPU means it has to run under an emulator which is slower than running native CPU instructions

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Not for x86 or ARM (and I believe SPARC), where the 32-bit execution is, as long as we're talking user-space is identical. There is a shim-layer for transitioning from user-space to 64-bit kernel, which may add a small amount of overhead, but generally, assuming the code isn't doing excessive amounts of for example 64-bit adds, the speed of execution for a given sequence is typically close. Since there are more registers in 64-bit, it can be more efficient in some cases, and of course 64-bit add etc are one instruction instead of two, so much faster.

Comment: Your example doesn't show a *statically* linked binary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short: Maybe.

The longer answer is:

It depends. You can't, for example, run a 64-bit binary on a 32-bit system, that's just not even nearly possible. Yes, it's the same processor family, but there are twice as many registers in the 64-bit system, which also has twice as long registers. What's the 32-bit processor going to "give back" for the value of those bits and registers that doesn't exist in the hardware in the processor? It just plain won't work. Some of the instructions also completely change meaning, so the system really needs to be "right" for the compiled code, or it won't work - fortunately, Linux will check this and plain refuse if it's not right.

You can BUILD a 32-bit binary on a 64-bit system (assuming you have all the right libraries, etc, installed for both 64- and 32-bit, etc).

Similarly, if you try to run ARM code on an x86 processor, or MIPS code on an ARM processor, it simply has no chance of working, because the actual instructions are completely different (or they would be in breach of some patent/copyright or similar, because processor instruction sets contain portions that are "protected intellectual property" in nearly all cases - so designers have to make sure they do NOT do "the same as someone else's design"). Like for 32-bit and 64-bit, you simply won't get a chance to run the wrong binary here, it just won't work.

Sometimes, there are subtle differences, for example ARM code can be compiled with "hard" or "soft" floating point. If the code is compiled for hard float, and there isn't the right support in the OS, then it won't run the binary. Worse yet, if you compile on x86 for SSE instructions, and try to run on a non-SSE processor, the code will simply crash [unless you specifically build code to "check for SSE, and display error if not present"].

So, if you have a binary that passes the above criteria, the Linux system tends to change a tiny bit between releases, and different distributions have subtle "fixes" that change things. Most of the time, these are completely benign (they fix some obscure corner-case that someone found during testing, but the general, non-corner case behaviour is "normal"). However, if you go from Linux version 2.2 to Linux version 3.15, there will be some substantial differences between the two versions, and the binary from the old one may very well be incompatible with the newer (and almost certainly the other way around) - it's hard to know exactly which versions are and aren't compatible. Within releases that are close, then it should work OK as long as you are not specifically relying on some feature that is present in only one (after all, new things ARE added to the Linux kernel from time to time). Here the answer is "maybe".

Note that in the above is also your implementation of the C and C++ runtime, so if you have a "new" C or C++ runtime library that uses Linux kernel feature X, and try to run it on an older kernel, before feature X was implemented (or working correctly for the case the C or C++ runtime is trying to use it).

Static linking is indeed a good way to REDUCE the dependency of different releases. And a good way to make your binary huge, which may be preventing people from downloading it.

Making the code open source is a much better way to solve this problem, then you just distribute your source code and a list of "minimum requirements", and let other people deal with it needing to be recompiled.

Comment: So whether the program will work depends on whether the kernel features used when compiling are compatible to the system it's run on?

Comment: Yes, that is the main factor once we're past "hardware compatibility" (e.g. 32-bit or 64-bit, SSE or not, etc)

Comment: Is backwards compatibility preserved in kernels then? Can I just compile on an old 32bit 2.* kernel and expect it to run on any 32 or 64 bit 2.* kernel?

Comment: There is an ambition to keep backwards compatibility, but there is not absolute guarantee. I've seen things break from one version to another. However, at work, I regularly run things on 3.4, 3.9 and 3.11 with the same (statically linked) binary. So it can work - to a large degree, it depends on exactly what the code does.

Comment: So in case kernel is not totally compatible with my static binary, I will not get an error straight away, but instead encounter a bug later, right?

Comment: CPU ISA's are **not** protected under international law. They're just numbers assigned to algorithms. That is neither protected by copyright law nor patents. However, specific implementations of algorithms may be protected, and that has been the case for Intel and MIPS.

Comment: I work for ARM, and I was recently told by someone from our legal department that they have patents protecting the instruction set. However, it may not be the entire instruction set, just parts of it. Point being that you can't (trivially) just build a completely compatible processor without some co-operation with the original manufacturer - unless the processor is old enough that such rights have expired. I'll make an edit to clarify.

Comment: Open source doesn't always help. Here in my company we have 5 different distributions and we would like to have one binary to reduce problem origins. Unfortunately getting all people to the same distribution isn't an option. And everybody compiling it's own source every week isn't too compelling either.

Answer (score 2):

In practice, it depends on "sufficiently simple". If you're using C++11, you'll quickly find that the C++11 libraries have dependencies on modern libc releases. In turn, those only ship with modern Linux distributions. I'm not aware of any "Long Term Support" Linux distribution which today (June 2014) ships with libc support for GCC 4.8

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, at least without serious hack.

Different linux distribution may have different glue code between user-space and kernel. For instant, an hello world seemingly without dependency built from ubuntu cannot be executed under CentOS.

EDIT: Thanks for the comment. I re-verify this and the cause is im using 32-bit VM. Sorry for causing confusion. However, as noted above, the rule of thumb is that even same linux distribution may sometime breaks compatibility in order to deploy bugfix, so the conclusion stands.

Comment: I literally just ran a hello world built with no special flags on xubuntu 14 on centos 6.5.

Comment: Really? I have done this more than once, so I'm slightly confused under what circumstance this DOESN'T work.

Comment: Maybe it matters if I'm running centos in a VM? I've added output to original post.

Comment: I have used this in both baremetal and VM. VM in itself should not alter the OS runtime as such - if it does, it's not a "true VM". (And you'd have to recompile the code for the VM vs. baremetal of the same OS, which would be pretty painful)

Comment: @Mats Petersson, sorry, I though you were telling me that this should not work. So finally, one can actually run hello world from ubuntu on centos.

Comment: Ah, my comment was against Calvin's original post, not your comment.